# Spring boot - Docker Frequently gateway Timeout 504

Tags: spring-boot, docker, dockerfile, microservices, devops

After migrating to docker, we are facing frequent 504 for specific microservice. I have used Eureka Server as Registry Server and Gateway Server will do authentication and redirection. For redirection we have used Zuul Proxy. We have used Feign Client and Ribbon Client for load balancing. Still we face 504 for that particular microservice.

Hosted docker in CentOS, 7 container running in docker service including MySQL container. All these are connected via custom docker network bridge

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I am facing a similar problem here.

Comment: @Franciso please check zuul configuration, I solved it through Zuul configuration in application property files

Comment: Thanks for answering, I have it working now.